# Worried about too many fields in table

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

i am currently planning out my next project which is a text based mmorpg game. I am currently trying to design certain parts of the database and have hit a bit of a problem that i have never had before. One part of the game allows the player to buy a car and add addons to it. I was going to have a different table altogether to manage the addons for the car, but a user could have up to 100 addons for a single car, which would require over 100 fields, of course i am not happy with this many fields in one table as it could become difficult to manage, is there any other way to split them up into multiple table?

Thanks

Comment: 100 fields? or 100 records? Use one record per addon... don't try to store them all in a single record. It's called AEV, attribute entity values

Comment: You can just serialize some data to one field, if you dont need to do lookups by it. ex json. NOSQL also is not bad option.

Comment: I have to disagree with alickus. Creating an inner platform is not a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why does each addon have to be a separate column?  Couldn't you have a many-to-many join table that would link car to addon?

```
Car
ID | Owner
1  | Jacob
2  |  Mary

Addon
ID | Name        | Price
1  | Flame decal | $10
2  | CD Changer  | $150

Car_Addon
Car_ID | Addon_Id
1      |  1
1      |  2
2      |  2
```

This indicates that Jacob's car has a flame decal and a cd changer, while Mary's car only has a cd changer.

Advantages of this approach:

- You can use foreign key constraints to ensure that no invalid records can be created
- It's easy to query in either direction -- which addons does this car have or which cars have a given addon
- The meaning of the relation is clear -- you're not relying on decoding serialized data within a single field
- You can store data about the association between car and addon -- the `car_addon` table can have a column for when the addon was added to that car, how it was paid for, whether it was part of a discount package, etc.

Comment: Ok, that is more of what i was thinking, its strange i have done stuff like that before but never thought of doing it that way. Thats great, thanks a lot.

Comment: This makes it very easy to query for all the current add-ons for a particular car.

Comment: You could also using bit masking and an extra field in the Car table to skip the car_addon table all together.

Comment: Alex -- I don't think this (bit masking) is a good approach.  The data stored in that field has no meaning other than the way you set up your application to parse it.  That makes your database both more fragile and less reusable.  This is a relational database -- use it to define the relation!

Answer (score 7):

You have a many-to-many relationship between cars and addons. You need an intermediary junction table to resolve that relationship.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.

Split them into multiple tables. If you have 100+ fields in a table, 99.9% of the time you haven't normalized your design enough. A sure sign of a badly structured database is a lot of sparsely populated fields.

Why are you hesitant to split it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a table for Cars (ID, Name) for example, one table for ADDON (ID, Name) too and another table to link these talbes called CAR_ADDON (idCar, idADDON).

That would be the best approach